# npm Bootsrap starting project for newbie

Tags: frontend, npm-install, bootstrap-5, npm-scripts, npm-package

I learned about Sass and Bootstrap, and now want to put it all together in a project using npm, but I’m completely lost.

Here’s what I’ve done so far:

```bash
$ npm init
// following the intructions//
$ npm install typescript
$ npm install bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1
$ npm install sass
```

I ended up with the following `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha1",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "name": "mytmpvpn-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

That’s the `package-lock.json`

```json
{
  "name": "mytmpvpn-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "mytmpvpn-frontend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.0-alpha1",
        "sass": "^1.57.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {}
    },
    "node_modules/@popperjs/core": {
      "version": "2.11.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@popperjs/core/-/core-2.11.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-50/17A98tWUfQ176raKiOGXuYpLyyVMkxxG6oylzL3BPOlA6ADGdK7EYunSa4I064xerltq9TGXs8HmOk5E+vw==",
      "peer": true,
      "funding": {
        "type": "opencollective",
        "url": "https://opencollective.com/popperjs"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/anymatch": {
      "version": "3.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/anymatch/-/anymatch-3.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KMReFUr0B4t+D+OBkjR3KYqvocp2XaSzO55UcB6mgQMd3KbcE+mWTyvVV7D/zsdEbNnV6acZUutkiHQXvTr1Rw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "picomatch": "^2.0.4"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/binary-extensions": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/binary-extensions/-/binary-extensions-2.2.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jDctJ/IVQbZoJykoeHbhXpOlNBqGNcwXJKJog42E5HDPUwQTSdjCHdihjj0DlnheQ7blbT6dHOafNAiS8ooQKA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/bootstrap": {
      "version": "5.3.0-alpha1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ABZpKK4ObS3kKlIqH+ZVDqoy5t/bhFG0oHTAzByUdon7YIom0lpCeTqRniDzJmbtcWkNe800VVPBiJgxSYTYew==",
      "funding": [
        {
          "type": "github",
          "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/twbs"
        },
        {
          "type": "opencollective",
          "url": "https://opencollective.com/bootstrap"
        }
      ],
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/braces": {
      "version": "3.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/braces/-/braces-3.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-b8um+L1RzM3WDSzvhm6gIz1yfTbBt6YTlcEKAvsmqCZZFw46z626lVj9j1yEPW33H5H+lBQpZMP1k8l+78Ha0A==",
      "dependencies": {
        "fill-range": "^7.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/chokidar": {
      "version": "3.5.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar/-/chokidar-3.5.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Dr3sfKRP6oTcjf2JmUmFJfeVMvXBdegxB0iVQ5eb2V10uFJUCAS8OByZdVAyVb8xXNz3GjjTgj9kLWsZTqE6kw==",
      "funding": [
        {
          "type": "individual",
          "url": "https://paulmillr.com/funding/"
        }
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "anymatch": "~3.1.2",
        "braces": "~3.0.2",
        "glob-parent": "~5.1.2",
        "is-binary-path": "~2.1.0",
        "is-glob": "~4.0.1",
        "normalize-path": "~3.0.0",
        "readdirp": "~3.6.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 8.10.0"
      },
      "optionalDependencies": {
        "fsevents": "~2.3.2"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/fill-range": {
      "version": "7.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fill-range/-/fill-range-7.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-qOo9F+dMUmC2Lcb4BbVvnKJxTPjCm+RRpe4gDuGrzkL7mEVl/djYSu2OdQ2Pa302N4oqkSg9ir6jaLWJ2USVpQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/fsevents": {
      "version": "2.3.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.3.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-xiqMQR4xAeHTuB9uWm+fFRcIOgKBMiOBP+eXiyT7jsgVCq1bkVygt00oASowB7EdtpOHaaPgKt812P9ab+DDKA==",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "optional": true,
      "os": [
        "darwin"
      ],
      "engines": {
        "node": "^8.16.0 || ^10.6.0 || >=11.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/glob-parent": {
      "version": "5.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/glob-parent/-/glob-parent-5.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-AOIgSQCepiJYwP3ARnGx+5VnTu2HBYdzbGP45eLw1vr3zB3vZLeyed1sC9hnbcOc9/SrMyM5RPQrkGz4aS9Zow==",
      "dependencies": {
        "is-glob": "^4.0.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/immutable": {
      "version": "4.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/immutable/-/immutable-4.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7WYV7Q5BTs0nlQm7tl92rDYYoyELLKHoDMBKhrxEoiV4mrfVdRz8hzPiYOzH7yWjzoVEamxRuAqhxL2PLRwZYQ=="
    },
    "node_modules/is-binary-path": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-binary-path/-/is-binary-path-2.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZMERYes6pDydyuGidse7OsHxtbI7WVeUEozgR/g7rd0xUimYNlvZRE/K2MgZTjWy725IfelLeVcEM97mmtRGXw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "binary-extensions": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/is-extglob": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-extglob/-/is-extglob-2.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-SbKbANkN603Vi4jEZv49LeVJMn4yGwsbzZworEoyEiutsN3nJYdbO36zfhGJ6QEDpOZIFkDtnq5JRxmvl3jsoQ==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/is-glob": {
      "version": "4.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-glob/-/is-glob-4.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-xelSayHH36ZgE7ZWhli7pW34hNbNl8Ojv5KVmkJD4hBdD3th8Tfk9vYasLM+mXWOZhFkgZfxhLSnrwRr4elSSg==",
      "dependencies": {
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/is-number": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-number/-/is-number-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-41Cifkg6e8TylSpdtTpeLVMqvSBEVzTttHvERD741+pnZ8ANv0004MRL43QKPDlK9cGvNp6NZWZUBlbGXYxxng==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.12.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/normalize-path": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-path/-/normalize-path-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-6eZs5Ls3WtCisHWp9S2GUy8dqkpGi4BVSz3GaqiE6ezub0512ESztXUwUB6C6IKbQkY2Pnb/mD4WYojCRwcwLA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/picomatch": {
      "version": "2.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/picomatch/-/picomatch-2.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-JU3teHTNjmE2VCGFzuY8EXzCDVwEqB2a8fsIvwaStHhAWJEeVd1o1QD80CU6+ZdEXXSLbSsuLwJjkCBWqRQUVA==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.6"
      },
      "funding": {
        "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/jonschlinkert"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/readdirp": {
      "version": "3.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/readdirp/-/readdirp-3.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hOS089on8RduqdbhvQ5Z37A0ESjsqz6qnRcffsMU3495FuTdqSm+7bhJ29JvIOsBDEEnan5DPu9t3To9VRlMzA==",
      "dependencies": {
        "picomatch": "^2.2.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/sass": {
      "version": "1.57.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sass/-/sass-1.57.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-O2+LwLS79op7GI0xZ8fqzF7X2m/m8WFfI02dHOdsK5R2ECeS5F62zrwg/relM1rjSLy7Vd/DiMNIvPrQGsA0jw==",
      "dependencies": {
        "chokidar": ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
        "immutable": "^4.0.0",
        "source-map-js": ">=0.6.2 <2.0.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "sass": "sass.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.0.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/source-map-js": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-js/-/source-map-js-1.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-R0XvVJ9WusLiqTCEiGCmICCMplcCkIwwR11mOSD9CR5u+IXYdiseeEuXCVAjS54zqwkLcPNnmU4OeJ6tUrWhDw==",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/to-regex-range": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/to-regex-range/-/to-regex-range-5.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-65P7iz6X5yEr1cwcgvQxbbIw7Uk3gOy5dIdtZ4rDveLqhrdJP+Li/Hx6tyK0NEb+2GCyneCMJiGqrADCSNk8sQ==",
      "dependencies": {
        "is-number": "^7.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/typescript": {
      "version": "4.9.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-4.9.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Uz+dTXYzxXXbsFpM86Wh3dKCxrQqUcVMxwU54orwlJjOpO3ao8L7j5lH+dWfTwgCwIuM9GQ2kvVotzYJMXTBZg==",
      "bin": {
        "tsc": "bin/tsc",
        "tsserver": "bin/tsserver"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.2.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": {
      "version": "2.11.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@popperjs/core/-/core-2.11.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-50/17A98tWUfQ176raKiOGXuYpLyyVMkxxG6oylzL3BPOlA6ADGdK7EYunSa4I064xerltq9TGXs8HmOk5E+vw==",
      "peer": true
    },
    "anymatch": {
      "version": "3.1.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/anymatch/-/anymatch-3.1.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KMReFUr0B4t+D+OBkjR3KYqvocp2XaSzO55UcB6mgQMd3KbcE+mWTyvVV7D/zsdEbNnV6acZUutkiHQXvTr1Rw==",
      "requires": {
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "picomatch": "^2.0.4"
      }
    },
    "binary-extensions": {
      "version": "2.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/binary-extensions/-/binary-extensions-2.2.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jDctJ/IVQbZoJykoeHbhXpOlNBqGNcwXJKJog42E5HDPUwQTSdjCHdihjj0DlnheQ7blbT6dHOafNAiS8ooQKA=="
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "version": "5.3.0-alpha1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ABZpKK4ObS3kKlIqH+ZVDqoy5t/bhFG0oHTAzByUdon7YIom0lpCeTqRniDzJmbtcWkNe800VVPBiJgxSYTYew==",
      "requires": {}
    },
    "braces": {
      "version": "3.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/braces/-/braces-3.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-b8um+L1RzM3WDSzvhm6gIz1yfTbBt6YTlcEKAvsmqCZZFw46z626lVj9j1yEPW33H5H+lBQpZMP1k8l+78Ha0A==",
      "requires": {
        "fill-range": "^7.0.1"
      }
    },
    "chokidar": {
      "version": "3.5.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar/-/chokidar-3.5.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Dr3sfKRP6oTcjf2JmUmFJfeVMvXBdegxB0iVQ5eb2V10uFJUCAS8OByZdVAyVb8xXNz3GjjTgj9kLWsZTqE6kw==",
      "requires": {
        "anymatch": "~3.1.2",
        "braces": "~3.0.2",
        "fsevents": "~2.3.2",
        "glob-parent": "~5.1.2",
        "is-binary-path": "~2.1.0",
        "is-glob": "~4.0.1",
        "normalize-path": "~3.0.0",
        "readdirp": "~3.6.0"
      }
    },
    "fill-range": {
      "version": "7.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fill-range/-/fill-range-7.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-qOo9F+dMUmC2Lcb4BbVvnKJxTPjCm+RRpe4gDuGrzkL7mEVl/djYSu2OdQ2Pa302N4oqkSg9ir6jaLWJ2USVpQ==",
      "requires": {
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1"
      }
    },
    "fsevents": {
      "version": "2.3.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevents/-/fsevents-2.3.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-xiqMQR4xAeHTuB9uWm+fFRcIOgKBMiOBP+eXiyT7jsgVCq1bkVygt00oASowB7EdtpOHaaPgKt812P9ab+DDKA==",
      "optional": true
    },
    "glob-parent": {
      "version": "5.1.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/glob-parent/-/glob-parent-5.1.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-AOIgSQCepiJYwP3ARnGx+5VnTu2HBYdzbGP45eLw1vr3zB3vZLeyed1sC9hnbcOc9/SrMyM5RPQrkGz4aS9Zow==",
      "requires": {
        "is-glob": "^4.0.1"
      }
    },
    "immutable": {
      "version": "4.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/immutable/-/immutable-4.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7WYV7Q5BTs0nlQm7tl92rDYYoyELLKHoDMBKhrxEoiV4mrfVdRz8hzPiYOzH7yWjzoVEamxRuAqhxL2PLRwZYQ=="
    },
    "is-binary-path": {
      "version": "2.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-binary-path/-/is-binary-path-2.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZMERYes6pDydyuGidse7OsHxtbI7WVeUEozgR/g7rd0xUimYNlvZRE/K2MgZTjWy725IfelLeVcEM97mmtRGXw==",
      "requires": {
        "binary-extensions": "^2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "is-extglob": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-extglob/-/is-extglob-2.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-SbKbANkN603Vi4jEZv49LeVJMn4yGwsbzZworEoyEiutsN3nJYdbO36zfhGJ6QEDpOZIFkDtnq5JRxmvl3jsoQ=="
    },
    "is-glob": {
      "version": "4.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-glob/-/is-glob-4.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-xelSayHH36ZgE7ZWhli7pW34hNbNl8Ojv5KVmkJD4hBdD3th8Tfk9vYasLM+mXWOZhFkgZfxhLSnrwRr4elSSg==",
      "requires": {
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1"
      }
    },
    "is-number": {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-number/-/is-number-7.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-41Cifkg6e8TylSpdtTpeLVMqvSBEVzTttHvERD741+pnZ8ANv0004MRL43QKPDlK9cGvNp6NZWZUBlbGXYxxng=="
    },
    "normalize-path": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/normalize-path/-/normalize-path-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-6eZs5Ls3WtCisHWp9S2GUy8dqkpGi4BVSz3GaqiE6ezub0512ESztXUwUB6C6IKbQkY2Pnb/mD4WYojCRwcwLA=="
    },
    "picomatch": {
      "version": "2.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/picomatch/-/picomatch-2.3.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-JU3teHTNjmE2VCGFzuY8EXzCDVwEqB2a8fsIvwaStHhAWJEeVd1o1QD80CU6+ZdEXXSLbSsuLwJjkCBWqRQUVA=="
    },
    "readdirp": {
      "version": "3.6.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/readdirp/-/readdirp-3.6.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-hOS089on8RduqdbhvQ5Z37A0ESjsqz6qnRcffsMU3495FuTdqSm+7bhJ29JvIOsBDEEnan5DPu9t3To9VRlMzA==",
      "requires": {
        "picomatch": "^2.2.1"
      }
    },
    "sass": {
      "version": "1.57.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sass/-/sass-1.57.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-O2+LwLS79op7GI0xZ8fqzF7X2m/m8WFfI02dHOdsK5R2ECeS5F62zrwg/relM1rjSLy7Vd/DiMNIvPrQGsA0jw==",
      "requires": {
        "chokidar": ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0",
        "immutable": "^4.0.0",
        "source-map-js": ">=0.6.2 <2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "source-map-js": {
      "version": "1.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-js/-/source-map-js-1.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-R0XvVJ9WusLiqTCEiGCmICCMplcCkIwwR11mOSD9CR5u+IXYdiseeEuXCVAjS54zqwkLcPNnmU4OeJ6tUrWhDw=="
    },
    "to-regex-range": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/to-regex-range/-/to-regex-range-5.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-65P7iz6X5yEr1cwcgvQxbbIw7Uk3gOy5dIdtZ4rDveLqhrdJP+Li/Hx6tyK0NEb+2GCyneCMJiGqrADCSNk8sQ==",
      "requires": {
        "is-number": "^7.0.0"
      }
    },
    "typescript": {
      "version": "4.9.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-4.9.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Uz+dTXYzxXXbsFpM86Wh3dKCxrQqUcVMxwU54orwlJjOpO3ao8L7j5lH+dWfTwgCwIuM9GQ2kvVotzYJMXTBZg=="
    }
  }
}
```

That’s the structure of my project folder:

```bash
$ npm ll
mytmpvpn-frontend@1.0.0
│ /home/user/local/dev/mytmpvpn-global/mytmpvpn-frontend
│ 
├── bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1
│   
├── sass@1.57.1
│   
└── typescript@4.9.4
```

My questions are the following:

1. Where do I start editing my `custom.scss` file for customizing Boostrap?
2. How can I make sure that Sass is "wathcing" my `custom.scss` file and compiling in the correct `.css` file?
3. More generally, what’s the best practice in terms of architecture for a front-end project like that? Do I create a folder `my-edits` for example and then do other folders for `html`, `scss`, `ts`, etc.